# Types and Typeclasses in Haskell: Missing field in record construction

Tags: haskell, exception, constructor, record

I have three datatypes:

```
data Person = Person { firstName :: String  
                     , lastName :: String  
                     , age :: Int  
                     , height :: Float  
                     , phoneNumber :: String  
                     , flavor :: String  
                     } deriving (Eq,Show, Read) 

data Car = Car {company :: String, model :: String, year :: Int} deriving (Eq,Show,Read)  

data Things = C Car | P Person deriving (Eq,Show,Read)
```

And I want to find the Car's coordinates in a [[Things]].

I tried:

```
enumerate = zip [0..]

findCar :: [[Things]] -> [(Int, Int)]
findCar things = do
        [(x, y)
          | (y, row) <- enumerate things
          , (x, thing) <- enumerate row
          , thing == C (Car { })]
```

But I got an Exception: 'Missing field in record construction company'.

How can I find coordinates of Car in a [[Things]] in a proper way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than checking whether your `thing` is equal to a specific `Car`, which is what `(==)` is for, you seem to want to check whether it's *any* kind of `Car`. So:

```
isCar (C Car{}) = True
isCar _ = False

findCar things =
    [ (x, y)
    | (y, row) <- enumerate things
    , (x, thing) <- enumerate row
    , isCar thing
    ]
```

(I've removed the unnecessary and potentially confusing `do` from `findCar`.)

Alternately, you could use the behavior of failed pattern matches in list comprehensions:

```
findCar things =
    [ (x, y)
    | (y, row) <- enumerate things
    , (x, C Car{}) <- enumerate row
    ]
```

This is a well-known trick, but a bit subtle and possibly confusing in a quick read of the code (since the match looks partial, but isn't), so it may be worth avoiding in a codebase shared between many programmers.

Comment: Is there any reason not to fold the third guard into the second in the second solution?

Comment: @HTNW No, not at all! Good suggestion; I'll improve the answer with it.